# How to change my Zoom background automatically each day (Mac)

Tags: zoom, wallpaper

I'm on Zoom calls a lot and I like to change my background picture each day.

Is there an easy way to automatically change the background picture in Zoom each day?

[image: Zoom background]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a clever way to change Zoom backgrounds each day. It involves:

- An app that changes the Mac desktop each day, and
- Creating a symbolic link between a Zoom file and the Unsplash file

First, download and install [Unsplash Wallpapers](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/unsplash-wallpapers/id1284863847?mt=12), which is a Mac app that gives a random desktop background on the Mac each day.

Now for the tricky part...

When Unsplash retrieves a picture and makes it the Mac's background picture, it is stored in something like:

```
/Library/Caches/Desktop Pictures/E2FB1A6A-5911-4C14-A561-8B9EB0C697BA/lockscreen.png
```

**Note:** The directory name might differ on your Mac, but it will be under `Desktop Pictures`.

Also, when you import a picture into Zoom to use it as a background, the picture is copied into:

```
/Users/YOUR-USERNAME/Library/Application Support/zoom.us/data/VirtualBkgnd_Custom/
```

You need to take a look at each of the pictures in that directory to figure out which one is the 'current' background in Zoom.

Then, you can create a [symbolic link](https://www.howtogeek.com/297721/how-to-create-and-use-symbolic-links-aka-symlinks-on-a-mac/) that points Zoom to the Unsplash location.

It will look like this (but **the random directory names might differ** on your Mac):

```
ln -s /Library/Caches/Desktop\ Pictures/E2FB1A6A-5911-4C14-A561-8B9EB0C697BA/lockscreen.png /Users/YOUR-USERNAME/Library/Application Support/zoom.us/data/VirtualBkgnd_Custom/098587E0-668E-4C0C-98FC-D27574347069
```

The result is that the Zoom background picture will automatically use the daily picture from Unsplash. If you open Unsplash Backgrounds in the menubar and change pictures, it will change for your next Zoom call.

Comment: Interesting solution. I'm going to try this myself! What version of macOS are you using on your Mac?

Comment: MacOS 12.5, but the solution should work for any version. The apps would behave the same.

Comment: Update: The image from Unsplash Wallpapers might be located in `/System/Volumes/Data/Users/YOUR-SERNAME/Library/Containers/com.unsplash.Wallpapers/Data/Library/Application Support/com.unsplash.Wallpapers/` However, it now seems that the filename keeps changing, which ruins the above process. Not sure what changed!